# How to locally define how a URL is resolved in Windows/IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-vista, url-routing, nameservers

I know that there is a way to make any defined URL resolve to a different URL, but I can't remember how or where to define this setting.

I understand this is ambiguous, so consider the following example.  I am building `http://www.webapplication.com`.  I have set up the web site in IIS 7.  However, I haven't forwarded the nameservers to resolve my server yet, so the URL points to somewhere else completely.  However, when I access `http://www.webapplication.com` locally, I would like the IIS 7 website to be resolved.

How can I do this?  Is this a setting in IIS, the individual browser (IE or Chrome) or somewhere else (like my network settings)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be using your `HOSTS` file.  You would want to edit it to add an entry for your domain name that maps to the IP address of the server.

[Here's a blog post describing the steps involved.](http://geekswithblogs.net/thibbard/archive/2006/12/13/ChangingYourHostsFileInVista.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

+1 to optus for the blog post on how to do this.  Just so the instructions are not lost if the blog post that optus mentions goes away, here is what you need to do:

1. Browse to Start -> All Programs -> Accessories
2. Right click "Notepad" and select "Run as administrator"
3. Click "Continue" on the UAC prompt
4. Click File -> Open
5. Browse to "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc"
6. Change the file filter drop down box from "Text Documents (*.txt)" to "All Files (*.*)"
7. Select "hosts" and click "Open"
8. Make the needed changes and close Notepad.  Save when prompted.

Comment: Rob, I selected optus because he posted the answer first, but I appreciate you posting the contents of the link.

Comment: @smartcaveman - No problem.  He most certainly deserved it for posting.  I've seen a few answers lost when blogs move or are shut down.  I've provided these same instructions to others in the past so wanted to make sure they were not lost and could be referenced again later.  Hope your project goes well.  Cheers!